# Manipulating element by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a plugin for Input Files, I created everything but without having in mind the possibility of having multiple inputs on screen, then it was necessary instead to manipulate the element from the element ID. This is so that actions in one input do not affect all other inputs on the screen.

Below is the code so far, I could not make it work when informed by the element ID.

```js
function bs_input_file() {
  // TODO: add function to hide remove button when file not informed
  const inputElement = $(".input-file").find('input');
  const inputId = inputElement.map(function (index, dom) {
                       return dom.id
                  });
  buttonInspec(inputId);

  function buttonInspec(id) {
    $("#" + id).find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");
    var element = $("#" + id).find('input');
    element.on("change input propertychange", function() {
      console.log("changed!")
      if (element.val() != "") {
        $("#" + id).find("button.btn-reset").removeClass("hidden");
      }
    });
  }
  // Necessary to put ID below also
  $(".input-file").before(
    function() {
      if (!$(this).prev().hasClass('input-ghost')) {
        var element = $("<input type='file' class='input-ghost' style='visibility:hidden; height:0'>");
        element.attr("name", $(this).attr("name"));
        element.change(function() {
          element.next(element).find('input').val((element.val()).split('\\').pop());
        });
        $(this).find("button.btn-choose").click(function() {
          element.click();
        });
        $(this).find("button.btn-reset").click(function() {
          element.val(null);
          $(this).parents(".input-file").find('input').val('');
        });
        $(this).find('input').css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).find('input').mousedown(function() {
          $(this).parents('.input-file').prev().click();
          return false;
        });
        return element;
      }
    }
  );
}

bs_input_file();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h3>Example</h3>
    <form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <!-- COMPONENT START -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier1">
            <input id="fileInput0" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />   
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier2">
            <input id="fileInput1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />   
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- COMPONENT END -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".input-file")` selects all elements with `class="input-file"`. To use an id instead: `function bs_input_file(id)` and `$("#" + id)`.

Comment: I tried with that but the code stopped working

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Use the `<>` button in the question editor.

Comment: Done. Add the code example

Comment: Please add code that reproduces the problem. Add a second form, and post the JS code you tried. Then test the snippet to make sure it does reproduce your issue. (i had to move jquery before bootstrap to make your snippet work)

Comment: Changed to problematic code

Comment: When you call `buttonInspec(inputId);`, `inputId` is a jQuery object containing multiple ids. You need `$.each(inputId, function (i, id) { buttonInspec(id); });` Or simply do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/v05ux2ra/

Comment: That solves the problem with multiple ids, but that still not working `$("#" + id).find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");` . This works: `$(".input-file").find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");`

Comment: `find()` only finds children. The reset button isn't a child of the input. Use `$("#" + id).parent().find(...`

Comment: Worked now! Thanks! But the function `element.on("change input propertychange", function() {` not get changes events, you know why?